# No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Web.Helpers'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

estoy trabajando en  un proyecto asp.net mvc con c#,  todo andaba bien hasta  que me aparecio este mensaje.

```
Error de servidor en la aplicación /.
No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Web.Helpers' ni una de sus dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código. 

Detalles de la excepción: System.IO.FileLoadException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Web.Helpers' ni una de sus dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Error de código fuente: 

Se ha generado una excepción no controlada durante la ejecución de la solicitud Web actual. La información sobre el origen y la ubicación de la excepción pueden identificarse utilizando la excepción del seguimiento de la pila siguiente.

Rastro al cargar el ensamblado: La información siguiente puede ser útil para determinar porqué no se cargó el ensamblado 'System.Web.Helpers'.


=== Información de estado anterior al enlace ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Helpers
 (Partial)
AVS: Se proporcionó información de enlace parcial para un ensamblado:
AVS: Nombre de ensamblado: System.Web.Helpers | Id. de dominio: 3
AVS: Un enlace parcial tiene lugar cuando solo se proporciona parte del nombre para mostrar del ensamblado.
AVS: Esto puede dar lugar a que el enlazador cargue un ensamblado incorrecto.
AVS: Se recomienda proporcionar una identidad textual completamente especificada para el ensamblado,
AVS: que consta del nombre simple, la versión, la referencia cultural y el token de clave pública.
AVS: Vea las notas del producto http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 para obtener más información y soluciones comunes a este problema.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Proyectos/SIGA/Iteracion I/Desarrollo/Codigo Fuente/Asea.Siga.MVC/SIGAMVC/SIGAMVC/
LOG: PrivatePath inicial = C:\Proyectos\SIGA\Iteracion I\Desarrollo\Codigo Fuente\Asea.Siga.MVC\SIGAMVC\SIGAMVC\bin
Ensamblado de llamada : (Unknown).
===
LOG: Este enlace empieza en el contexto de carga default.
LOG: Utilización del archivo de configuración de la aplicación: C:\Proyectos\SIGA\Iteracion I\Desarrollo\Codigo Fuente\Asea.Siga.MVC\SIGAMVC\SIGAMVC\web.config
LOG: Utilizando el archivo de configuración de host: C:\Users\User\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Utilizando el archivo de configuración del equipo en C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: La directiva no se está aplicando a la referencia en este momento (enlace de ensamblado privado, personalizado, parcial o basado en la ubicación).
LOG: Intento de descarga de la nueva dirección URL file:///C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/64b12119/b896b54a/System.Web.Helpers.DLL.
LOG: Intento de descarga de la nueva dirección URL file:///C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/64b12119/b896b54a/System.Web.Helpers/System.Web.Helpers.DLL.
LOG: Intento de descarga de la nueva dirección URL file:///C:/Proyectos/SIGA/Iteracion I/Desarrollo/Codigo Fuente/Asea.Siga.MVC/SIGAMVC/SIGAMVC/bin/System.Web.Helpers.DLL.
LOG: Utilización del archivo de configuración de la aplicación: C:\Proyectos\SIGA\Iteracion I\Desarrollo\Codigo Fuente\Asea.Siga.MVC\SIGAMVC\SIGAMVC\web.config
LOG: Utilizando el archivo de configuración de host: C:\Users\User\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Utilizando el archivo de configuración del equipo en C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Redirección detectada en el archivo de configuración de aplicaciones: 1.0.0.0 se redirigió a 3.0.0.0.
LOG: Referencia posterior a la directiva: System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Intento de descarga de la nueva dirección URL file:///C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/64b12119/b896b54a/System.Web.Helpers.DLL.
LOG: Intento de descarga de la nueva dirección URL file:///C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/64b12119/b896b54a/System.Web.Helpers/System.Web.Helpers.DLL.
LOG: Intento de descarga de la nueva dirección URL file:///C:/Proyectos/SIGA/Iteracion I/Desarrollo/Codigo Fuente/Asea.Siga.MVC/SIGAMVC/SIGAMVC/bin/System.Web.Helpers.DLL.
AVS: Al comparar el nombre de ensamblado se generó la incompatibilidad: Versión principal
ERR: Error al completar la instalación del ensamblado (hr = 0x80131040). Finalizó la búsqueda.

Seguimiento de la pila: 


[FileLoadException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Web.Helpers' ni una de sus dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)]

[FileLoadException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ni una de sus dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +36
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +21
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ni una de sus dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +738
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +217
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +92
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +290
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +549

[HttpException (0x80004005): No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ni una de sus dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10074680
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

Información de versión: Versión de Microsoft .NET Framework:4.0.30319; Versión ASP.NET:4.7.3160.0
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es posible que la versión referenciada del ensamblado System.Web.Helpers en el proyecto no coincida con la versión mencionada en el archivo web.config.

- Compruebe la versión referenciada de System.Web.Helpers.
- Verifique el archivo web.config en la raíz de la aplicación web y valida
  si hay una entrada para System.Web.Helpers y verifique que sea la
  misma que la de la versión de referencia.

Sino agrega la referencia a System.Web.Helpers.dll en el proyecto, puede que tengas que hacerlo por nuget y luego revisa en el web.config donde diga algo como esto que la version es correcta

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```